# what would be the simpler way to accomplish this SQL row to column transpose?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is the table from a select:

```
+---------+-------+------------+-----------------------------+-------+
|   id    | name  |    date    |          dtinsert           | hour  |
+---------+-------+------------+-----------------------------+-------+
| 1355428 | Max   | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-16 13:29:21.2500000 | 11:26 |
| 1355433 | Max   | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-16 13:31:07.5133333 | 11:29 |
| 1355436 | Peter | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-16 13:32:52.1600000 | 11:30 |
| 1355445 | Peter | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-16 13:36:34.9466667 | 11:33 |
| 1355456 | Troy  | 2019-12-16 | 2019-12-16 13:41:22.7300000 | 11:36 |
+---------+-------+------------+-----------------------------+-------+
```

this is what I want

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|              1              |              2              |              3              |              4              |              5              |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1355428                     | 1355433                     | 1355436                     | 1355445                     | 1355456                     |
| Max                         | Max                         | Peter                       | Peter                       | Troy                        |
| 16/12/2019                  | 16/12/2019                  | 16/12/2019                  | 16/12/2019                  | 16/12/2019                  |
| 2019-12-16 13:29:21.2500000 | 2019-12-16 13:31:07.5133333 | 2019-12-16 13:32:52.1600000 | 2019-12-16 13:36:34.9466667 | 2019-12-16 13:41:22.7300000 |
| 11:26                       | 11:29                       | 11:30                       | 11:33                       | 11:36                       |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure this is sql?

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Will the amount of columns be dynamic or static? E.g. Will the output table always have 5 columns or will this change based on different numbers of ID's?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: SQL tables/result sets are not spreadsheets, however similarly they may be presented. Columns and Rows are *not* the same sorts of things (notably, everything in a column has to be of the same data type). It would be far better to do this transpose in a *presentation layer* (application or report builder) than to try and do it in SQL.

Comment: The numbers of columns would change based on the numbers of id returned

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a dynamic pivot-table. First you need to declare all the columns that should be created. This is done with the `@Cols` declaration. Then you need to make a call which contains all the columns, which is done in the `@SQL` declaration here. Lastly the call is executed by an EXEC. As I don't have the data due to the image, I can only explain the logic, not the actual end-result, but if you add the data as a table, I can adjust the query to that.

```
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(1000)

    SET @Cols = Stuff((
                SELECT DISTINCT ',' + ' ' + QuoteName(ID) + ''
                FROM [TableName] A
                ORDER BY 1
                FOR XML Path('')
                ), 1, 1, '') + ''

      --  Print @Cols

 SET @SQL = ' 

    Select
            Name
            ,' + @Cols + '
         From  [TableName] A
          Pivot (MAX([Columns]) For [ID] in ( ' + @Cols + ')
          ) as pvt
          '

        --  Print @SQL
        EXEC (@SQL)
```